# Splitting state-county-MSA string variable

Tags: r, string, split

I have a variable below that I believe is separated by space.

```
 [95] "Florida          Volusia        Deltona-Daytona Beach-Ormond Beach"            
 [96] "Iowa             Polk           Des Moines"                                    
 [97] "Mississippi      Hinds          Jackson"                                       
 [98] "Georgia          Richmond       Augusta-Richmond"                              
 [99] "Ohio             Mahoning       Youngstown-Warren-Boardman"                    
[100] " Pennsylvania       Lackawanna             Scranton--Wilkes-Barre"             
[101] " Pennsylvania       Dauphin                Harrisburg-Carlisle"                
[102] " Florida            Brevard                Palm Bay-Melbourne-Titusville"      
[103] " Utah               Utah                   Provo-Orem"                         
[104] " Tennessee          Hamilton               Chattanooga"                        
[105] " North Carolina     Durham                 Durham"
```

I want to create three *variables* out of this string - state, county, and MSA. But the usual string split commands are not working. I tried *stringi* command too but fail to split the variable.  Not sure why this is happening, as the command works on simpler strings.

```
> strsplit(BK_state_county_MSA$non_squished_states_county_MSA_names_df,"")
Error in strsplit(BK_state_county_MSA$non_squished_states_county_MSA_names_df,  : 
  non-character argument

> BK<-strsplit(as.character(BK_state_county_MSA$non_squished_states_county_MSA_names_df),"\\t")
> str(BK) #List of 0
 list()

> stri_split(str=BK_state_county_MSA$non_squished_states_county_MSA_names_df, regex="\\t",n=3)
list()

> BK <-stri_split_lines(BK_state_county_MSA$non_squished_states_county_MSA_names_df)
list()
```

EDIT - The original data has 104 observations, but I am posting only 8 observations with dput command...

```
>  dput(BK_state_county_MSA)
structure(list(non_squished_state_county_MSA = c(
"New York             Bronx                New York-Wayne-White Plains", 
"New York             Kings                New York-Wayne-White Plains",  
" Pennsylvania       Lackawanna             Scranton--Wilkes-Barre", 
" Pennsylvania       Dauphin                Harrisburg-Carlisle", 
" Florida            Brevard                Palm Bay-Melbourne-Titusville", 
" Utah               Utah                   Provo-Orem",
" Tennessee          Hamilton               Chattanooga", 
" North Carolina     Durham                 Durham")), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Actually looks tab-separated. Tab separated data has that blocky appearance. R's read functions `might` handle that well because it "compresses" multiple repeated instances of "whitespace" characters. The problem occurs if there are embedded spaces within tab-separated values. Consider using read.delim rather than read.table and see if you get better results.

Comment: @IRTFM The data above is from a pdf file that I imported into R using ```pdf_text``` command and did some preliminary cleaning.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option using `stri_trim_left()` from `stringi` and `separate()` from `tidyr`:

`stri_trim_left()` removes strings with a leading whitespace, which occurs in your data starting at `[100]`. You can then `separate()` the strings into the three specified columns `state`, `country` and `MSA`, separated by at least 2 whitespaces (`sep = " {2,}"`).

**Data**

```
BK_state_county_MSA<- structure(list(non_squished_state_county_MSA = c(
  "New York             Bronx                New York-Wayne-White Plains", 
  "New York             Kings                New York-Wayne-White Plains",  
  " Pennsylvania       Lackawanna             Scranton--Wilkes-Barre", 
  " Pennsylvania       Dauphin                Harrisburg-Carlisle", 
  " Florida            Brevard                Palm Bay-Melbourne-Titusville", 
  " Utah               Utah                   Provo-Orem",
  " Tennessee          Hamilton               Chattanooga", 
  " North Carolina     Durham                 Durham")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                       -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Code**

```
library(tidyr)
library(stringi)

BK_state_county_MSA %>% mutate(non_squished_state_county_MSA = stri_trim_left(non_squished_state_county_MSA)) %>%
  separate(non_squished_state_county_MSA, into = c("state", "country", "MSA"), sep = " {2,}")
```

**Output**

```
           state    country                           MSA
1       New York      Bronx   New York-Wayne-White Plains
2       New York      Kings   New York-Wayne-White Plains
3   Pennsylvania Lackawanna        Scranton--Wilkes-Barre
4   Pennsylvania    Dauphin           Harrisburg-Carlisle
5        Florida    Brevard Palm Bay-Melbourne-Titusville
6           Utah       Utah                    Provo-Orem
7      Tennessee   Hamilton                   Chattanooga
8 North Carolina     Durham                        Durham
```

Comment: I get the following error using the mutate command ```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `string`.
ℹ `string = stri_trim_left(BK_state_county_MSA$non_squished_states_county_MSA)`.
ℹ `string` must be size 104 or 1, not 0.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.```  @Gnueghoidune

Comment: The string variable  upon which I run the mutate command ``` > str(BK_state_county_MSA)
'data.frame': 104 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ non_squished_state_county_MSA: chr  "New York             Bronx                New York-Wayne-White Plains" "New York             Kings                New York-Wayne-White Plains" "New York             New York             New York-Wayne-White Plains" "New York             Queens               New York-Wayne-White Plains" ...
> str(BK_state_county_MSA$non_squished_states_county_MSA)
 NULL``` @Gnueghoidune

Comment: @ArvindSharma could you please dput(BK_state_county_MSA) your data.frame in your original question?

Comment: Added. Also, can you please tell me @Gnueghoidune if you had to manually convert the tail data I posted into dataframe (by removing the observation number) or you used a command / trick in Excel or Word.  I can see with ```dput``` one can easily paste the data into R.

Comment: @ArvindSharma See the update, works for me. As for the data, I copy/pasted them. There are ways to import data, such as using `read.table()`, but there were brackets and no column names provided. It's usually muuuuuch better to provide a `dput()`, as you thankfully added to your question :)

Comment: I prefer the ```dput()``` solution for ease of replication too, and and declaring the list as a dataframe solution works for me now.  Thanks.  Also, when I used the ```tail``` command to generate the original data, you copy/pasted the original data but had to manually remove the row numbers and insert the commas, right? Since it was only 10 obs, you did it by hand right?  Or you you copy/pasted the *tail* data into say R data editor (like Stata allows) and R generated the import data commands which you posted here for solution (I doubt you did this) ?

Comment: I did it manually (including deleting of row numbers), since it was only one vector to copy.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably something useful, in terms of further data analysis, about keeping North with Carolina and New with York & etc. And it's always nice to have a one liner, but sometimes a few lines get you where is best for moving forward. Consider playing around like this:

```
maddening_txt <-  " North Carolina     Durham                 Durham"
strsplit(maddening_txt, split = '    ') # n space = 4L
[[1]]
[1] " North Carolina" " Durham"         ""                ""               
[5] ""                " Durham"
nchar(strsplit(maddening_txt, split = '    ')[[1]])
[1] 15  7  0  0  0  7
# you could throw in a which test for >0 for indexing here
strsplit(maddening_txt, split = '    ')[[1]][c(1,2,6)]
[1] " North Carolina" " Durham"         " Durham"
 string_vec <- strsplit(maddening_txt, split = '    ')[[1]][c(1,2,6)]
> string_vec[1]
[1] " North Carolina"
string_vec[2:3]
[1] " Durham" " Durham"
```

Left as it is, when returned to in the future, something like `split='    '` begs 'How many spaces was that?'
So, more explicitly, and using some of the above notation:

```
> strsplit(sc_msa$entries[8], split='\\s{5,}')
[[1]]
[1] " North Carolina" "Durham"          "Durham"
```

This appears to also remove leading left white space without recourse to `trim`. And then the above mentioned
`for`

```
sc_msa_lst <- list()
> for(i in 1:length(sc_msa$entries)) {
+ sc_msa_lst[[i]] <- strsplit(sc_msa$entries[i], split='\\s{5,}')
+ }
> sc_msa_lst
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "New York"                    "Bronx"                      
[3] "New York-Wayne-White Plains"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "New York"                    "Kings"                      
[3] "New York-Wayne-White Plains"


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] " Pennsylvania"          "Lackawanna"             "Scranton--Wilkes-Barre"


[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
[1] " Pennsylvania"       "Dauphin"             "Harrisburg-Carlisle"


[[5]]
[[5]][[1]]
[1] " Florida"                      "Brevard"                      
[3] "Palm Bay-Melbourne-Titusville"


[[6]]
[[6]][[1]]
[1] " Utah"      "Utah"       "Provo-Orem"


[[7]]
[[7]][[1]]
[1] " Tennessee"  "Hamilton"    "Chattanooga"


[[8]]
[[8]][[1]]
[1] " North Carolina" "Durham"          "Durham"
```

So, our regex pattern, '\s{5,}' works for cases seen so far. Next, I have to remember how to make a data.frame...there's got to be a list of lists to data.frame question on SO somewhere that'll help me.

A completely unacceptable answer, but it will get you to the guts of what simplifications are offering and provide more control going forward.

Data, with renaming:

```
sc_msa <- structure(list(entries = c("New York             Bronx                New York-Wayne-White Plains", 
"New York             Kings                New York-Wayne-White Plains", 
" Pennsylvania       Lackawanna             Scranton--Wilkes-Barre", 
" Pennsylvania       Dauphin                Harrisburg-Carlisle", 
" Florida            Brevard                Palm Bay-Melbourne-Titusville", 
" Utah               Utah                   Provo-Orem", " Tennessee          Hamilton               Chattanooga", 
" North Carolina     Durham                 Durham")), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```